# Doctrine EM -> getting data from 2 entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table: sms_followers. I have 2 entities: clubs and users. I know how to insert data into the table, but i cant get the data out of it. Can anyone give me some support?

I wanne check if the userid with the club ID already exists.

My code till now:

```
$club = $this->em->getRepository('Club')->findBy(array('id' => $clubid));
$user = $this->em->getRepository('User')->findOneBy(array('id' => $this->auth->getUser()->getId()));

$notifiction = $user->getSmsfollower();
```

see it like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT userid, clubid FROM sms_followers WHERE clubid=value AND userid=value';

echo $row['clubid'];
echo $row['userid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:** using Doctrine **DBAL** you can create a query like this:

```
$stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
            ->getConnection()
            ->prepare('SELECT userid, clubid FROM sms_followers WHERE clubid=? AND userid=?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, $userid);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $clubid);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

see the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html)